# Shift Reduce Conflict

Tags: grammar, yacc

This is a part of a grammar which implemented with YACC.

```
%right NOT
%left TIME DIV REALDIV MOD
%left LT LE
%left GT GE
%left EQ NE
%left AND OR
%right ASSIGN
%%
expression: expression EQ expression {}; 
|expression PLUS expression {};
| expression TIME expression{};
| PLUS expression {};
| variable PLUS PLUS {};
| variable {};
```

It has 9 shift reduce conflict.
How to fix conflicts without changing the language? (the string which is generated with this grammar)

Answer (score 1):

As written, the grammar is ambiguous because there is no way to distinguish the operator `++` from two instances of `+`.

Normally, this problem is resolved in the lexical scanner using the "maximal munch" rule, so that the expression `a+++b` would broken into the lexical items `ID PLUSPLUS PLUS ID`, resulting in the parse `(a++) + b`. In that case, if the user really meant `a + (+ (+b)))` and didn't want to use parentheses, they could simply split the tokens up with whitespace, writing `a+ + +b`. (In your grammar, `<=` is apparently scanned as a single lexical token, rather than the tokens `<` and `=`, so the inputs `a < = b` and `a <= b` result in different parses -- one of which is invalid. That's more or less expected. So there's no obvious reason why `+ +` should be a permitted spelling of the increment operator `++`.)

Making that change will change the language slightly. In your grammar, `a++b` can be interpreted as `a+(+b)`; if `++` were lexically scanned as a single token, the resulting expression would be a syntax error. If that's a problem it can be resolved but I don't think the resulting complexity is worthwhile.